# [Karate][Standalone] Error - JavaFX Error

Tags: karate

I have just started playing with Karate for API testing for one of my project written in golang. I have downloaded the standalone jar as mentioned in the docs. I am getting jfx error one after the other.

```
java --version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

On first run I get below error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
```

I checked on the internet and found error is related to openjfx and hence installed the same. And now I am getting below error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
```

I am not sure If there is something missing on the platform or I am making some mistake.

Comment: I would imagine you need to place the openjfx .jars and .so files into the JDK  lib/ext  folder?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the very latest version of Karate, we removed the JavaFX dependency in version 0.9.5 onwards.